# Python serial port ussd command throw error

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial, at-command

I am using pyserial with AT command to query a Huawei USB modem k3565. Some commands such as `ser.write(b'at+cimi\r\n')` return the imsi of the career. But when I try to get the phone number with the code below. It returns an error. Could it be my modem or platform(ubuntu 17.04) or my code.

```
In [35]: ser.write(b'at+cusd=1, "*99#", 15\r\n')
Out[35]: 23

In [36]: ser.read_all()
Out[36]: '\r\nERROR\r\n'
```